# Check if any item is null of System.Collections.IList

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `System.Collections.IList` (non-generic) and I would like to check, if any item in the list is null. With Linq I would and the `IEnumerable<T>` extensions it would look like:

```
bool hasNoNullItems = myList.All(x => x != null);
```

Is there any way to do this with `System.Collections.IList`?

Comment: @Liam Thanks, updated my question. For would be my fallback:)

Comment: What isin this collection?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Objects of any type. In some cases null items are added.

Comment: Why you have to store different types in the same collection at all? Are there also value types or nullable types?

Comment: @Liam That makes sense, why does ReSharper always gives me the hint to change Any to All? Strange.

Comment: @Mi.Sharp: not in this case. Resharper suggests that if you use `!seq.Any(...)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok I answerd your question bad. The list contains only one type of items (type is not important at this point). The list is declared in external library so I can't change to generic.

Comment: @Mi.Sharp: then i would use `mylist.Cast<RealType>().Any(x => x == null)` and it's generic so you could also access `RealType`s properties if needed without additional cast. If there are different types and you want to check only `RealType` you can use `mylist.OfType<RealType>()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-generic collection can contain *anything*, thus it can only safely be cast to `object`.

Thus the following two appraoches are fairly equivalent:

```
bool anyNull = false;
foreach(object o in myList)
{
    if(o == null)
    {
        anyNull = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

and:

```
var anyNull = myList.Cast<object>().Any(x ==> x == null);
```

or also:

```
var anyNull = myList.Cast<object>().All(x ==> x != null);
```

The same applies if you know the exact type at compile-time. You´d have to cast to the `RealType`, either using this

```
myList.Cast<RealType>()
```

which is equivalent to

```
foreach(RealType o in myList)
```

Comment: Problem of myList.OfType<RealType> would only be in case of null items. They would not be part of result IEnumerable.

Comment: @Mi.Sharp You´re right. I deleted that part on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Cast__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) extension that works on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
bool hasNullItems = myList.Cast<object>().Any(x => x == null);
```

Note that `All(x => x != null)` is `true` if there is *no* `null` item. Thatswhy I use `Any(x => x == null)` to check if *any item is null*.

Comment: He uses `All != null` which is the same, but i like your approach more too

Comment: @TimSchmelter and in OP's current version `hasNullItems` is inversed.